# What is the Republican motivation for supporting the Trans-Pacific Partnership?

Tags: united-states, congress, policy, economy, republican-party

I don't understand why Republican moderates like Boehner and Paul Ryan are pushing so hard for the Trans-Pacific Partnership. What is it they are trying to achieve? I have looked for statements by Ryan on the TPP and have not found any. Why are they supporting it?

Comment: "Obamatrade"? I haven't even heard Fox News use that term yet.

Answer (score 5):

The [Trans-Pacific Partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Pacific_Partnership) is a proposed (free?) trade agreement heralded by big business.

Both the Democratic and Republican parties and most of their candidates are heavily funded by big business.  Arguably the Republican party in particular, but that could be just my impression, I don't have evidence to back it up.

Therefore, Most of them support the Trans-Pacific Partnership.  Perhaps quietly so.

If anything, opposition comes from the left.  For example, senator [Bernie Sanders](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/05/bernie-sanders-michael-froman-tpp_n_6419874.html):

> It is incomprehensible to me that the leaders of major corporate interests who stand to gain enormous financial benefits from this agreement are actively involved in the writing of the TPP while, at the same time, the elected officials of this country, representing the American people, have little or no knowledge as to what is in it

Comment: My understanding of this agreement is free trade is a pretty far stretch, its mostly crony capitalism granting multinational companies the ability to not follow laws of countries they operate in.

Comment: @Ryathal Good point.  I have changed *free* to *(free?)* as it does depend on who one asks and interpretation.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Do you agree with Ryathal that it is basically crony capitalism? That would explain why Ryan isn't talking about the benefits of the agreement.

Comment: @TylerDurden I have not studied TPP in sufficient detail to comment on that.  As a European I'm more familiar with TTIP and that one is pure crookery.

Comment: " The Republican party in particular." I'd appreciate a citation on that (I can ask a separate Q). An honest one, which - in Big Business - includes Big Law and Big Labour.

Comment: @DVK I certainly do not agree with including the labour movement with big business, *in particular* since in this context it's about support for the Trans-Pacific Partnership which I believe is not something the labour movement is terribly happy with.  Either way, I've added that I believe it is just my impression that the Republicans are more heavily funded by big business than the Democrats and that I have no evidence to back this up.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, Republicans are not pushing for the TPP yet. The only bill that has gone through congress was one to grant authority to the president to negotiate an agreement and then send it to congress for a simple up/down vote [as has been done for many previous trade deals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_track_(trade)). Allowing congress to amend of filibusterer the agreement could potentially destroy the delicately negotiated agreement between the large number of parties.

Once the final agreement has been negotiated Republicans will have to decide whether or not to support it. At that point we will hear the arguments for and against the specific measures in the TPP

That being said, one of the stated goals of the agreement is to lower tariffs between a large number of nations. Free trade is a core value for many economics minded Republicans. To quote [Paul Ryan](http://www.nationaljournal.com/congress/paul-ryan-trade-tpa-obama-gamble-20150609) "We believe in free trade. That is one of our party's primary principles." It's generally seen as enriching American consumers and creating jobs even if there are some losses where America doesn't have comparative advantage. It's at least conceivable that the TPP will lead to freer trade. That being said, if the president does [(again)](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/wp/2012/10/23/how-obamas-tire-tariffs-have-hurt-consumers/) bow to special interests over the interest of consumers, then the house can always vote down the measure.

Since there is plenty of bipartisan cronyism in congress the final TPP will probably have to have some corrupt clauses, but there might be enough legitimate tariff reduction to make it a net good in the eyes of a genuinely free trade Republican like Paul Ryan.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying he is supporting it because it will potentially lower foreign tariffs and that is the only reason?

Comment: @TylerDurden not just foreign tariffs; reducing domestic tariffs, quotas, or excessive trade regulations would be just as big a victory for a free trade Republican. We won't know what comes out of the negotiations for a while though.

Comment: @TylerDurden - not just "because of specific tariff" - they support free trade ON PRINCIPLE, as a Good Thing for all involved long term.